# motion reconstruction from a single camera

Tags: image-processing, 3d, computer-vision

I have a single calibrated camera (known intrinsic parameters, i.e. camera matrix K is known, as well as the distortion coefficients).

I would like to reconstruct the camera's 3d trajectory. There is no a-priori knowledge about the scene.

simplifying the problem by presenting two images that look on the same scene and extracting two set of corresponding matched feature points from them (SIFT, SURF, ORB, etc.)
My problem is how can I calculate the camera extrinsic parameters (i.e. the rotation matrix R and the translation vector t ) between the to viewpoints?

I have managed to calculate the fundamental matrix, and since K is know, the essential matrix as well. using [David Nister's efficient solution to the Five-Point Relative Pose Problem](http://citeseerx.ist.psu.edu/viewdoc/download?doi=10.1.1.129.1518&rep=rep1&type=pdf) I've managed to get 4 possible solution but:

1. the constraint on the essential matrix E ~ U * diag (s,s,0) * V' doesn't always apply - causing incorrect results.
   [EDIT]: taking the average singular value seems to correct the results :) one down
2. how can I tell which one of the four is the correct one?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your solution to point 1 is correct: diag( (s1 + s2)/2, (s1 + s2)/2, 0).

As for telling which one of the four solutions is correct, only one will give positive depths for all points with respect to the camera frame. That's the one you want.

Code for checking which solution is correct can be found here: http://cs.gmu.edu/%7Ekosecka/examples-code/essentialDiscrete.m from http://cs.gmu.edu/%7Ekosecka/bookcode.html
They use the determinants of U and V to determine the solution with the correct orientation. Look for the comment "then four possibilities are". Since you're only estimating the essential matrix, it's susceptible to noise and does not behave well at all if all of the points are coplanar.

Also, the translation is only recovered to within a constant scaling factor, so the fact that you're seeing a normalized translation vector of unit magnitude is exactly correct. The reason is that the depth is unknown and estimated to be 1. You'll have to find some way to recover the depth as in the code for the eight-point algorithm + 3d reconstruction (Algorithm 5.1 in the bookcode link.)

The book the sample code above is taken from is also a very good reference. http://vision.ucla.edu/MASKS/ Chapter 5, the one you're interested in, is available on the Sample Chapters link.

Comment: This is exactly what I'm trying to understand. for each combination of R/R' and t/-t I triangulate the points and get a set of 3d points. I plot the camera in such way that their focal point is at t, and looking towards the Z axis, rotated by R. I expected that in the correct combination all the point will lay in front of the two cameras - and in some case it never happens. I think my plotting is wrong..

And one more question if I may: in the results I always get that |t| (the norm of t) is always 1, an unwanted constraint since the distance between the cameras can be different that 1...

Comment: I've updated my answer to address your questions since I didn't think I could get all that into a comment. Let me know if any of that doesn't make sense.

Comment: I looked into the examples and I think I need to calculate R and t from all the images at the same time, as seen in the step_by_step.m example.I need chapter 8 in order to understand how they do it,since  there is no documentation in the code, I can't understand what is done...

Comment: The 8-point algorithm in the book uses at least 8 matched points from each of two images to estimate the essential matrix. (Algorithm 5.1 on pg. 121) I can't get to the document from the link you give in your original question so I'm not sure how you're calculating the relative rotation. For 3D reconstruction you might try http://cs.gmu.edu/%7Ekosecka/examples-code/compute3DStructure.m since it uses the simpler linear triangulation.

Comment: I've updated the link in the question, though it is not relevant any more since I'm using the eight points algorithm.
I've managed to find R and t up to scale and reconstruct the 3D structure. My problem is that since R and t are correct upto scale, when trying to add another set of points (from a different pair of images), I cannot register them since it's a different scale factor. I think I need to reconstruct from at least 3 views in order to reconstruct from multiple(>2) cameras.

Comment: I've never played with more than 2 simultaneous views, but as you say it's in chapter 8. If you can't find the book in your local university library, you might try Google books. There are several pages missing from the Google version, but it might be enough to get a handle on the sample code.

Answer (score 0):

Congrats on your hard work, sounds like you've tried hard to learn these techniques.
For actual production-strength code, I'd advise to download [libmv](http://code.google.com/p/libmv/) and [ceres](http://code.google.com/p/ceres-solver/), and re-code your solution using them.

Your two questions are really one: invalid solutions are rejected based on the data you have collected. In particular, Nister's (as well as Stewenius's) algorithm is normally used in the inner loop of a RANSAC-like solver, which selects for the solution with the best fit / max number of inliers.

Comment: Hello Franco and thank you for your answer. I'm trying to make as less as possible use of 3rd party code. Generating the solution with Matlab/opencv should not take more than a couple of lines ( if you know what to write that is ) and I would like to try solving it my self.  :)